# How to start a finished thread again?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I run some code inside a thread (A). At the end of that thread it creates another thread (B). Now what i want to do is at the end of thread B, i need to call thread A. when i do

`_threadA.start()` from thread B system says: `Thred alread started.`

how to fix this?

Comment: Once a thread stops you cannot restart it......

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to understand the [life cycle of threads](http://www.roseindia.net/java/thread/life-cycle-of-threads.shtml); after a thread is started it can not be restarted - the same applies for a stopped thread, once it's stopped its life cycle is over. Take a look at the linked article, in particular the state diagram will make things clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a stopped thread means you should call again the stopped thread. that's only the way to do it .